# Symfony2 display related entity property in Twig template

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

Let's say I have a Product class and a Category class. Each Product has 1 Category. On the list of products (generated by calling `php app/console doctrine:generate:crud`), I would like to display the category name for each product. However everything I've tried so far doesn't work.

I'm using the KnpPaginatorBundle (don't know if it makes a difference or not).

Here's the code inside the controller:

```
// ProductController.php

public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT p
        FROM MyMainBundle:Product p
        ORDER BY p.name'
    );

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate($query, $request->query->get('page', 1), 10);

    return $this->render('MyMainBundle:Product:index.html.twig', array(
        'pagination' => $pagination,
    ));
}
```

Here's the code inside the template:

```
{# index.html.twig #}
{% extends 'MyMainBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Category</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for entity in pagination %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.category }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {{ knp_pagination_render(pagination) }}
{% endblock %}
```

I've added a __toString() method to the Category class:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getName();
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Method "category " for object "My\MainBundle\Entity\Product" does not exist in MyMainBundle:Product:index.html.twig at line 16

I've tried adding `LEFT JOIN p.category category` to my query, to no avail.

I've tried replacing `{{ entity.category }}` by `{{ entity.category.name }}`, in which case I get:

> Method "name " for object "Proxies__CG__\My\MainBundle\Entity\Category" does not exist in MyMainBundle:Product:index.html.twig at line 16

I've tried replacing `{{ entity.category }}` by `{{ entity.getCategory }}` in which case I get:

> Method "getCategory " for object "My\MainBundle\Entity\Product" does not exist in MyMainBundle:Product:index.html.twig at line 16

I've tried replacing `{{ entity.category }}` by `{{ entity.getCategory() }}` in which case I get:

> Unexpected token "name" of value " " ("end of print statement" expected) in MyMainBundle:Product:index.html.twig at line 16

How am I supposed to display the category name?

Comment: It seems that the association is not defined right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that in both your error messages:

> Method "category " for object "My\MainBundle\Entity\Product" does not exist in MyMainBundle:Product:index.html.twig at line 16

and

> Method "name " for object "Proxies_*CG*_\My\MainBundle\Entity\Category" does not exist in MyMainBundle:Product:index.html.twig at line 16

you have a space between the method name and the following `"`.

This happened to me before when typing my code too quickly: I pressed the key to make the Twig `}}` before typing the space after the property name, so I ended up having a non-breaking space between the property and the `}}`, which Twig doesn't like and takes as part of the property name.

Check if you don't have a non-breaking space in your code before the `}}`.

Comment: Exactly. I'm using a French keyboard ([AZERTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY)), so I have to use AltGr to type the closing curly brackets. It turns out I pressed AltGr one character too early, and, in Ubuntu, AltGr+Space results in a non-breaking space. I actually spotted the non-breaking space before reading your post, but StackOverflow wouldn't let me answer my own question within 8 hours of posting it.

Comment: Still have same error in 2K24. Thx for this question.